# Are there solutions to know which verbs are followed by the infinitive or the gerund?

Tags: usage, infinitives, gerunds, complements

I can know some patterns like these.

> I enjoy cooking.
>
> He wants to swim.

But for other verbs like *admit*, *allow*, *agree*, *appear* and so on. It seems that I have to remember which verbs are followed by infinitives or gerund.

I know I have to listen a lot. At least I know how to use "can't help" from this song "but I can't help falling in love with you...."

But for learner do we have only to remember them or are there any other solutions?

Comment: I'm afraid there is no shortcut - you have to learn them one by one.

Comment: And there are some which allow both; we can say either "I like cooking" or "I like to cook."

Comment: What is the difference of the meaning between  "I like cooking" or "I like to cook?

Comment: @nkm There's no difference between those sentences. They are semantically the same; both are functioning as the **direct object** of ***like***. *Cooking* and *to cook* are both nouns in your example. *You like what?* ***to cook/cooking.***

Answer (score 5):

I will try to answer this from a learner's point of view.

I agree with @StoneyB. In the end, you will need to know each and every one of them. Up to this point, I couldn't find "one rule to cure them all" yet. But after spending years learning English, at some point I realized this very useful guideline on my own. This guideline helps me choose the correct pattern most of the time!

Here is my guideline,

> You need to understand the subtle difference between **"I stop thinking"** and **"I stop to think"**, and you should understand it really really well.

If you understand that well, you will be able to figure out why *"he was to leave"* means the same to *"he was **going** to leave"*. For example, *Clark announced that he **was to leave** the show to concentrate on his music career.* You can also rephrase it to *... he **was leaving** the show...*, and it will still have roughly the same meaning. Just like your case of *"like cooking"* vs. *"like to cook"*.

Although ***"I like cooking"*** and ***"I like to cook"*** would mean the same to most native speakers, you can think of *"cooking"* and *"to cook"* differently. And you can still be right!

Personally, when I heard  *"cooking"*, I will think of **the act of cooking**. When I heard *"to cook"*, I will in my mind see myself (or someone else, depending on the context) getting up and **start to cook**. Either way, I will end up cooking, which is why I believe thinking this way is quite close to native speakers.

That's the way I see it.

Comment: You could also write: *Clark announced that he was leaving the show to concentrate on his music career*.

Comment: Exactly! I thought I should mention that, but then I was too focused on his "like cooking" vs "like to cook". I will add that.

Answer (score 2):

The most common use of [infinitives](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/627/03/) is, as you've recognized from the pattern in your examples, when they follow another verb. Most of the time, when this happens--if the verb is transitive--the [infinitive](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/gerunds.htm) is the either the direct object or it's part of a phrase that is the direct object. (e.g., *I [have/had] agreed to ride with her* I agreed to do what? **To ride with her**).

And while they're technically verbs, infinitives can function as nouns/adjective, just as gerunds can. So ask yourself, *What part of speech is this?*

> e.g., **To be prepared** first is **a good idea** [subject is *to
>   be prepared*; direct object is *a good idea*]

If it's a complement, an object, or the subject, infinitives can be used.

Also, I use **bare** infinitives frequently in the subjunctive mood, which is another very common use.

> e.g., I suggest you **be** home when I get there. Were I you, I'd be
>   there.

Additionally:

> It seems that I have to remember which verbs are followed by
>   infinitives or gerunds.

Yes, that's correct, although I wouldn't necessarily call them [*gerunds*](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/gerunds.htm) (because they're not used as nouns/adjectives). Words with the *-ing* suffix function as verbs when they immediately follow an auxiliary. They're used to form the continuous/progressive tenses.

> But for other verbs like admit, allow, agree, appear and so on. It
>   seems that I have to remember which verbs are followed by infinitives
>   or gerunds.

It's still the same rule. The infinitive functions as a different part of speech.

e.g.:

> I **am trying *to agree with you.*** [present progressive; direct
>   object is *to agree*]
>
> You **appear *to be angry***. [object is *to be angry*]
>
> She **has been allowing *him to sleep on her couch***. [present perfect
>   progressive; object is *to sleep (on her couch)*]
>
> I **was planning *to go out***. [past progressive; *to go out*
>   is object]
>
> They **were walking *to lose weight***. [*to lose weight* is the object]
>
> I **have been drinking *to get drunk***. [present perfect
>   progressive; *to get drunk* is the object]
>
> Before I **began *to careen down the mountainside***, I **had been trying *to ski***. [*to careen down the mountainside* is the object of the dependent clause; *to ski* is the direct object of the past perfect progressive *had been trying*]

Here are two examples of an infinitive as a complement:

> **To bodly go where no man has gone before**, one has got **to be prepared** [subject is *one*; object is *to be prepared*; complement
>   is *to boldly go where no man has gone before*]
>
> **To eat spicy food**, you've got **to have a tolerance** for burning sensations. [subject is *you*; object is *to have a tolerance*;
>   complement is *to eat spicy food*]

If it can be replaced with another noun or adjective, including gerunds, an infinitive can be used.

Oh, and:

> At least I know how to use "can't help" from this song " but I can't
>   help falling in love with you...."

You could rewrite that as *I can't help **but to fall in love with you***. *But **to fall** in love* and *falling* are **both** the objects of *[can't] help*. Sometimes you need **to alter** the syntax, though, as I've done in the above example. As long as you're using the correct syntax--and they're **not** used as verbs--you can usually substitute an infinitive for a gerund.