# Do you use "like walking" or "like to walk"?

Tags: verbs, gerunds, infinitives, infinitive-vs-gerund

OK, my German friend asked me this the other day and I couldn't give her an answer! Native English speaker for 27 years and it's still hard for me, ha-ha.

> Do you like to walk?
>   Do you like walking?

What is correct?
Are they both correct?

Obviously we can substitute 'walk' for many other verbs, so is there a rule here or something?

Comment: I answered something similar once: http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/13955/3281.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verbs of [liking and disliking are generally followed by gerunds](http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/verbs-followed-ing-clauses).

> Do you like walking? - is more natural over the second one.

They come under 'verb patterns' and there is a list of which verb takes what [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/329/when-should-a-verb-be-followed-by-a-gerund-instead-of-an-infinitive).